# Copy/paste Excel charts to PowerPoint Error

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to take 60 charts in an Excel workbook and paste them to PowerPoint. It has been working fine up until we converted to Office 365. Now I am getting an error

> The specified data type is unavailable

Here is the code:

```
copy_chart "318Pivot", "cht404_318", 3

Public Function copy_chart(sheet, chart, slide)
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim PPApp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object
Dim PPShape As Object

Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (slide)

Worksheets(sheet).Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart).chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

' paste and select the chart picture
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteJPG  '**This is where it errors out**

'With PPShape
For j = 1 To PPSlide.Shapes.Count
With PPSlide.Shapes(j)
    If .Type = msoPicture Then
        .LockAspectRatio = False
        .Height = 5# * 72
        .Width = 10# * 72
        .Left = 0# * 72
        .Top = 1.5 * 72
    End If
End With
Next j
DoEvents

' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing
Set PPShape = Nothing

End Function
```

It worked great before. I have tried `ppPasteDefault` and `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` but they both made the PowerPoint file >30 MB. Before when it worked, it was 3 MB.

Does anyone know why I can't use ppPasteJPG anymore all of the sudden and how to correct the code?

Comment: What about `ppPastePNG`?

Comment: Try stepping through the code to see if it generates the same error.

Comment: ppPastePNG and stepping thru the code gave me the same result.  driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

If ytou are not using early binding, Excel VBA won't know what ppPasteJPG means. But ppPasteJPG is merely a named constant with a value of 5. So replace

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteJPG
```

with

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=5
```

Comment: `PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=5` didn't work either.

Comment: Are there any References that changed with Office 365?  BTW this code is being run from Access since the Excel data is being generated from Access.  Not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: I stepped thru it again just to see what was on the clipboard before pasting.  So after CopyPicture, I went to PowerPoint manually to do a PasteSpecial and the only two options there were Picture (Enhanced Metafile) and Picture (Windows Metafile).  Why are those the only options?  Now I can see why the errors for PNG and JPG, just not how to correct.

Comment: Your code was using `CopyPicture` with type `xlPicture`, so the paste types only allowed metafiles. If you had used type `xlBitmap` you could have used JPG. In most cases, PNG gives better visual results than JPG. Sorry I missed that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Found that the copy line was not actually copying the Chart for some reason.  Not sure why copy ChartArea works and copy Chart does not though.

```
'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart).chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
Worksheets(sheet).Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chart).Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
' test to see if the clipboard is empty

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

' paste and select the chart picture
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteJPG
```